# RxScala buffer elements

Tags: rx-scala

I have application where I need parse strings and I use for it RxScala. My code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
import rx.lang.scala.Subject
import rx.lang.scala.schedulers.NewThreadScheduler
import rx.lang.scala.subjects.{SerializedSubject, PublishSubject}
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration

object RxScala extends App {
  val subject: Subject[String] = SerializedSubject(PublishSubject())

  val processLines = (lines: Seq[String]) => {
    // long action
  }

  subject
    .subscribeOn(NewThreadScheduler())
    .tumblingBuffer(Duration(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS), 100)
    .subscribe(processLines)

  for(i <- 1 to 100000) {
    subject.onNext("Line " + i)
  }
}
```

I have problem because I add lines faster then I can process them.

I want create buffer e.g. 200 lines and if buffer is full ignore new records to moment when buffer isn't full, e.g.

```
Add 100 records (A)
Add 100 records (B)
Program start processLines (A) // buffer have (B) elements
Add 100 records (C) // buffer have (B, C) elements and it is full
Add 100 records (D) // elements are ignored
ProcessLines is finished 
Program start processLines (B) // buffer have (C) elements
Add 100 records (E) // buffer have (C, E) elements
```

Does RxScala have method to do this?

Comment: Have you tried out `onBackpressureDrop`?

Answer (score 0):

```
subject.
    tumblingBuffer(Duration(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS), 100).
    onBackpressureDrop.
    observeOn(NewThreadScheduler()).
    subscribe(processLines)
```

http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/backpressure.html

> onBackpressureDrop
>       drops emissions from the source Observable unless there is a pending request from a downstream Subscriber, in which case it will
>   emit enough items to fulfill the request